# Describing the outer automorphism of a special unitary group in terms of the Hermitian form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $h$ be a non-degenerate Hermitian form on $\mathbb{C}^n$ with signature $(p,q)$. Let $\U_h$ denote the associated unitary group. This is a subgroup of $\GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ of real dimension $n^2$. Let $\SU_h$ denote the subgroup consisting of matrices with determinant 1. I believe this is a simply connected group, though possibly noncompact if $h$ is indefinite.

I also believe the outer automorphism group of $\SU_h$ is the automorphism group of the Dynkin diagram $A_{n-1}$, which has order 2 if $n\ge 3$. (What's a good way to see this?)

Assuming this, for $n\ge 3$, there is a unique nontrivial outer automorphism $\sigma$. This does not determine a unique automorphism, but at least when $h$ is the standard (positive definite) Hermitian form on $\mathbb{C}^n$, there is a pretty canonical-looking representative of $\sigma$, given by the (complex) conjugate, or equivalently inverse transpose. In fact this is also the case as long as the standard basis is orthogonal with respect to $h$ (equivalently: the Gram matrix of $h$ w.r.t. the standard basis is diagonal).

The issue is that I really understand the relationship between the complex conjugate and $h$. The unitary group is determined by $h$, and expressible in terms of $h$, so in some sense the unique nontrivial outer automorphism should also be. My question is how do we do this?

A more precise question is: given a random nondegenerate Hermitian form $h$ on a complex vector space $V$, is there a nice way to write down a representative of the unique nontrivial outer automorphism of $\U_h$ in terms of $h$ *without choosing a basis of $V$*?

My first thought is to consider the adjoint (if $A$ is an operator, its adjoint $A^*$ is the unique operator satisfying $h(Av,w) = h(v,Aw)$ for all $v,w$). For $A$ unitary, this means $A^* = A^{-1}$. This comes close, since the complex conjugate is just the inverse transpose, but to get all the way I'd also have to be able to express the transpose "intrinsically" in terms of $h$.

Comment: You don't have to choose a *basis* of $V$, but you do have to choose a *real structure*, i.e., an $\mathbb{R}$-subspace $R\subset V$ such that $V = R \oplus iR$.  Equivalently, you have to choose an $\mathbb{R}$-linear 'conjugation' $J:V\to V$ such that $J(iv) = -iJ(v)$ and $J^2=\mathrm{id}$.   You have to make *some* choice because 'the' non-inner automorphism is not unique.  Only its equivalence class modulo the inner autormorphisms is unique.

Comment: @RobertBryant can you explain how to write down the automorphism if you have a real structure? Eg if $V$ is just $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the standard real structure, and $A$ is a unitary operator relative to a “non diagonal” Hermitian form $h$, how do you write down the outer automorphism?

Comment: Well, you do have to choose the real structure $R$ to be real with respect to $h$, i.e., $h(v,w)$ is real for $v,w\in R$.  (This can be shown to be possible via induction on the dimension of $V$.)  Then $J$ is the identity on $R$ and minus the identity on $iR$.  Then an outer involution of $U_h$ is just $\sigma(A) = -JAJ$.  The fact is, though, that there's no canonical choice of $\sigma$, the only thing that's 'canonical' is the class of $\sigma$ in the group $\mathrm{Out}(U_h)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Nice! A couple more questions. Why do you use $-JAJ$ vs $JAJ$? Also, I was able to verify that $JAJ$ is indeed unitary for $h$, but my proof involves breaking $A$ into real and imaginary parts, and it's not an entirely enlightening calculation. What's your preferred way of seeing that $JAJ$ is unitary?

Comment: @RobertBryant Also, is it correct that every non-inner automorphism can be realized as $A \mapsto -JAJ$ (or $JAJ$, I'm still a bit confused about this) for $J$ coming from some real structure? Do you know of a reference where some of this is worked out?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I momentarily forgot that $J^2$ is the identity, not minus the identity, so the correct formula is indeed $\sigma(A) = JAJ$.  (I shouldn't have used the letter $J$, since I usually reserve that for an anti-complex map whose square is minus the identity.)  But, yes, any outer *involution* (non-inner automorphism that squares to the identity) of $SU_h$ is of this form for some $J$.  I think this is discussed in Helgason's *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces*.